# How to obtain "wp_rest" nonce for WP Statistics plugin manually?

Tags: wordpress, nonce

During my pentest of a client's websites I stumbled upon the WP with vulnerable WP Statistics plugin installed.

To exploit this vulnerability, I should send a JSON-API request to endpoint `/json-api/wp-statistics/v2/...`. The problem is I must send correct `_wpnonce` along with my request.

I found a cool explanation here:
https://gist.github.com/Xib3rR4dAr/5dbd58b7f57a5037fe461fba8e696042

They recommend to extract the `_wpnonce` value from the legitimate URLs from the website page source. But I don't see similar URLs anywhere. My guess is that the plugin installed but not correctly used so it doesn't create these links within the pages.

As I understand, this plugin uses `wp_rest` action for nonce and it means that the nonce used is global for the whole JSON REST API. Am I correct here? And if yes, how can I obtain this nonce value manually?